# 301 Redirection for friendly Urls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to redirect a friendly url from a wordpress site to asp.net site.

e.g http://www.oldsite.com/blog/2012/11/stress-less-at-christmas-with-natural-health-products/

to

http://www.newsite.com/category/stress-less-at-christmas-with-natural-health-products.aspx

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but how to do so depends on the kind of web server your WordPress site is hosted on. If it is using Apache (the usual for Linux, but sometimes used on Windows), you'll want to [use mod_rewrite to remap the URLs via regex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).

If WordPress is running on IIS (the typical for Windows servers), you can install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if you have control of the server, or you can ask your hosting provider if it is included. Once that is installed, you can do similar [remapping of the URLs with regex](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).